# Setting "from address" in WP_Mail headers causes email to go to spam

Tags: php, wordpress, email, spam-prevention

I have a section of code that is executed when a new user creates an account on my site. The code grabs the specific HTML template from within my site, and replaces placeholders with the new customer details and then fires the email off.

```
$email_template = file_get_contents(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/emails/New_user_account_mail.html');

$html = str_replace(
                           ['[user_first_name]', '[user_email]', '[user_security_code]' ],
                           [ $new_account_first_name, $new_account_email, $url  ],
                           $email_template);

$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');


wp_mail( $new_account_email, 'Please activate your account', $html, $headers);
```

This code works fine, and an email is sent using the standard admin@mydomain.co.uk email, however as soon as i try to set the "from address" all the mails suddenly get directed into the spam folder.

If i revert back to my original code, the, emails instantly get delivered to the normal inbox.

I've been setting the from address with the following:

```
$headers[] = 'From: my name <welcome@mydomain.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
```

It is probably worth noting i am using Mailjet SMTP, and i have SPF as well as DKIM configured correctly on my domain.

I would have though that because my domain was authorised, that i'd be able to send emails with any email related to it. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there a way to set the "from address" without then causing the mail to go to the spam box?

Any comments / help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the "\r\n" at the end of the From header? Couldn't that be dropped?

Comment: You don't need the ` . "\r\n"` in there. it will automatically combine the header array with the proper formatting. Can you provide the scoring that is putting the emails into the spam folder? Most spam systems describe why the email failed to pass.

Comment: I didn't realise about the ' . "\r\n" ' in the header, so thanks for letting me know. 
Apologies, i'm unsure how i check the scoring of the mail. I'm using the online Outlook site, so will look for a way to get some information, and get back to you.